# Decorating class methods by overriding __new__ doesn't work?

Tags: python, metaclass, python-internals

I want to decorate all the methods of my class. I have written a sample small decorator for illustration purpose here.

Decorator:

```
def debug(func):
    msg = func.__name__

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(msg)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper 

def debugmethods(cls):
    for key, val in vars(cls).items():
        if callable(val):
            setattr(cls, key, debug(val))
    return cls
```

Now I want to decorate all the methods of my class. One simple way is to use @debugmethods annotation on top of my class but I am trying to understand two other different approaches for doing so.

a) Overriding `__new__`

```
class Spam:
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        clsobj = super().__new__(cls)
        clsobj = debugmethods(clsobj)
        return clsobj

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def foo(self):
        pass

    def bar(self):
        pass

spam = Spam()
spam.foo()
```

b) Writing metaclass

```
class debugmeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, clsdict):
        clsobj = super().__new__(cls, clsname, bases, clsdict)
        clsobj = debugmethods(clsobj)
        return clsobj

class Spam(metaclass = debugmeta):     
    def foo(self):
        pass

    def bar(self):
        pass

spam = Spam()
spam.foo()
```

I am not sure

1. Why " a) overriding `__new__` " doesn't work ?
2. Why signature of method `__new__` is different in metaclass?

Can someone help me understand what am I missing here.

Comment: A metaclass creates classes, a class creates instances. The `__new__` method signatures reflect this.

Comment: Makes sense. You mean to say there is `__new__` method from metaclass also getting called in a)? If yes then when does that `__new__` gets called and who is making that call?

Comment: No, `__new__` in `a)` is called to create an *instance* of the `Spam` class. `super().__new__()` returns that instance. You don't have a class there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You appear to be confused between `__new__` and metaclasses. `__new__` is called to create a new object (an instance from a class, a class from a metaclass), it is not a 'class created' hook.

The normal pattern is:

- `Foo(...)` is translated to `type(Foo).__call__(Foo, ...)`, see [special method lookups](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup) for why that is. The `type()` of a class is it's metaclass.
- The standard `type.__call__` implementation used when `Foo` is a custom Python class will call `__new__` to create a new instance, then call the `__init__` method on that instance if the result is indeed an instance of the `Foo` class:

  ```
  def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):  # Foo(...) -> cls=Foo
      instance = cls.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)  # so Foo.__new__(Foo, ...)
      if isinstance(instance, cls):
          instance.__init__(*args, **kwargs)        # Foo.__init__(instance, ...)
      return instance
  ```

  So `Foo.__new__` is not called when the `Foo` class itself is created, only when *instances* of `Foo` are created.

You don't usually need to use `__new__` in classes, because `__init__` suffices to initialise the attributes of instances. But for *immutable* types, like `int` or `tuple`, you can only use `__new__` to prepare the new instance state, as you can't alter the attributes of an immutable object once it is created. `__new__` is also helpful when you want change what kinds of instances `ClassObj()` produce (such as creating singletons or producing specialised subclasses instead).

The same `__call__` -> `__new__` and maybe `__init__` process applies to metaclasses. A `class Foo: ...` statement is implemented by calling the metaclass to create a class object, passing in 3 arguments: the class name, the class bases, and the class body, as a dictionary usually. With `class Spam(metaclass = debugmeta): ...`, that means `debugmeta('Spam', (), {...})` is called, which means `debugmeta.__new__(debugmeta, 'Spam', (), {...})` is called.

Your first attempt *a*, setting `Spam.__new__` doesn't work, because you are *not creating a class object* there. Instead, `super().__new__(cls)` creates an empty `Spam()` *instance* with no attributes, so `vars()` returns an empty dictionary and `debugmethods()` ends up doing nothing.

If you want to hook into class creation, then you want a metaclass.

Comment: This is an amazing explanation. Thanks a lot for the detailed write-up, this clears my doubt.

Comment: Extremely informative, thank you Martijn! I was exactly looking for the standard `type.__call__` implementation. Where did you get it from?

Comment: @Maggyero: from the [C source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5e0ce46aeb13f31e4dbe6a2891f583e770e0a808/Objects/typeobject.c#L955-L1005).

Comment: Thank you for the reference.